# Have signing UMDF USB driver dll requirements changed?

Tags: code-signing, umdf

I have a UMDF USB driver that works with WinUSB to communicate with my company's USB imagesetter interface boxes.
This driver is signed and working in its current version, but we need to make some changes.

Our original signing certificate has expired and we have acquired a new signing certificate, but when I try and sign the new DLL I get the following:

```
"signtool.exe" sign /v /f ".\mycert.pfx" /p <redacted> /ac "VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5.cer"  /n MyCompany /t http://time.certum.pl/ "MyINF.cat" 
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

The signing certificate contains the following information:

```
Organization    MyCompany, USA
Requested On    20-OCT-2014 7:27 AM by MyBoss
Last Reissued   14-APR-2015 6:55 AM
Platform        Microsoft Authenticode
Validity        20-OCT-2014 to 03-JAN-2018
Serial Number   <MySerialNumber>

Issued to: MyCompany, USA
Issued by: DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA
Expires:   Wed Jan 03 13:00:00 2018
SHA1 hash: 48DD5D40AF53A295F494305935791F216E31A5AB
```

Can anyone suggest a reason why this certificate is not suitable for signing my driver DLL when it appears to be suitable for signing my custom printer port monitor DLLs?

Thanks,

Peter